# How to solve index match formula with multiple criterias and repeated occurences of values

Tags: indexing

Hi I would like to ask for help in constructing my formula. For better understanding, please see my reference table for Overall coaching status: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAK9D.png)
Coaching status per TM: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJE5a.png)

This is the table im using to reference the first and second table uploaded: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuVbY.png)

In column S of the last table uploaded, I want to find the count of the coaching status of each TM based on the week inputted in the dropdown on column O. I was able to get the 'endorsed' count but I keep on getting the first occurence of values for Retracted until Pending. Please help

This is the formula I used for overall 'endorsed': =ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1,(O3=$B:$B)*(R3=D:D),0)))
Formula for overall 'retracted':  =ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1,(O4=$B:$B)*(R4=D:D),0)))

This is the formula per TM endorsed: =ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX($L:$L,MATCH(1,(O3=$H:$H)*(Q8=$J:$J)*(R8=$K:$K),0)))
Formula for TM1 retracted: =ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX($L:$L,MATCH(1,(O4=$H:$H)*(Q9=$J:$J)*(R9=$K:$K),0)))